# Getting nested array Index from an _id in mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

This seems to be the season at work where mongo stumps me all the time. I will be given an item array index and a call._id. Not the call array index. I need to somehow get the index for that call id.So far I've been unable to do this. I've tried using arrayFilters and I also tried $indexOfArray.

```
use mydb

var lineNum = 0;
var callId = ObjectId("MY ID HERE");

var query = {
    "items.calls._id":callId
              
};

var update = {
     "$set": {
            
            //THIS WORKS
            [`items.${lineNum}.updatedTs`] : new Date(),
            
            //THIS DOES NOT WORK
      
            [`items.${lineNum}.calls.$[items.calls._id].message.takenBy.firstName`]: "Dani",

        }
        
};

var options = {
    multi: true, 
    arrayFilters: [
        {"items.calls._id", callId}
    ]
};

db.getCollection("myCollection").update(query,update,options);
```

What am I missing? For this example the callIndex should be: 0 but I am getting

```
"errmsg" : "BSON field 'update.updates.arrayFilters.0' is the wrong type 'string', expected type 'object'",
    "code" : 14,
```

I've been at this for days now. This is just my most recent attempt. I must be missing something with the way arrays filters work.

Edit to add example doc

```
[
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("Some Mongo ID"),
    "lastUpdatedByName" : "",
    "lastUpdatedTs" : ISODate("2023-06-07T12:45:30.927+0000"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "updatedBy" : {
                "firstName" : "",
                "lastName" : "",
            },
            "updatedTs" : ISODate("2023-06-07T12:45:30.927+0000"),
            "calls" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("Some Mongo ID"),
                    "message" : {
                        "status" : "Resolved",
                        "updatedBy" : {
                            "firstName" : "",
                            "lastName" : "",
                            "username" : ""
                        },
                        "updatedTs" : ISODate("2023-06-07T12:45:31.457+0000"),
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
  }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share the collection schema?

Comment: @PauloFernando is this what you mean? I provided an edit.

Comment: Are `"items.calls._id"` values unique across the entire collection?  ... and/or unique within a document?

Comment: something like [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sojpM0R_xY5)

Comment: ... or depending on the uniqueness of `"items.calls._id"`, something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E-scMfB6JNS)?

Comment: @cmgchess That actually ended up being what worked! I ended up doing an array filter on the item and the call id since it was unique. My syntax was wrong this line ```{"items.calls._id", callId}``` changed to this: ```{"items.calls._id":  callId}``` is what finally fixed the above code and let it run without error.

Comment: glad u got it working

Comment: @Daniella you can write answer with what worked for you